# How to open last opned folder in QFileDialog using PyQt

Tags: pyqt4

I want to know is it possible to open last browsed folder using `QFileDialog`

I used `QFileDialog` to browse and select a file.

**Step 1**

I browsed `c:\test\files` and selected xyz filde from that folder

**Step2**

Again when i need to browse for files. This time i want `QFileDialog` to point to my last visited folder (i.e., `c:\test\files`)

I know its is possible to do by saving the current visited directory and use `QFileDialog.setDirectory` to set the previous directory.

Is there any other option like savelast path browse, something like that....?

Is it possible...?

If YES how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `saveState()` and `restoreState()` methods  in conjunction with QSettings, but this is just a variant of saving the last path even if probably it is a better method